# jQuery AutoComplete Plugin Extension - How to pass to the bind keyup event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using the following plugin which extends the jQuery AutoComplete UI Plugin:

https://github.com/experteer/autocompleteTrigger/blob/master/jquery-ui.autocompleteTrigger.js

The select method is passed a UI variable:

```
select:function(event, ui) {
```

I need the ui variables in the

```
.bind("keyup", function(event) {
```

How can I get the ui variable in the .bind ?

Thanks

Comment: wow, that plugin looks sweet ;)

Comment: @AnApprentice: What would you expect `ui` to contain in the `keyup` event? The user has not selected an item yet (one may be under focus though). What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to reference `event.target` in your `select` function.  Or you can pass `this`:

```
.bind("keyup", function(event) {
    select(event, this);  
});
```